# Unable to access Asset files in Metro app

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am trying to read a text file, which is shipped as an asset in a Metro app. I am receiving an access denied error, if specifying the file path as "ms-appx:///Assets/file.txt". Clearly I need to set some capability to access installation location folder. I tried enabling all capabilities in manifest designer, but still the same error. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
    new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/file.txt"));
Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
```

Comment: It works! Yay! Thanks a lot, buddy! I was directly passing the path instead of creating Uri. Any idea, why passing filename directly didn't worked? It works for other file paths, right.

Comment: Not sure, btw. you had wrong the path prefix. It must be "ms-appx:///", not "ms:appx////"

Comment: Actually, I mentioned it wrong here. My mistake. I just used new Uri function in the old code, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is that exactly the reference you are using? Try

```
ms-appx:///Assets/file.txt
```

Comment: Oops. Sorry, typing mistake there. Should have copied it.