# In a Modern Windows App (Metro), opening an excel file that is included in the app itself

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

SO I'm trying to create an app where I have an excel file in the app itself and then open it in excel when a user presses the button.  I'm fairly new at this so I'm not terribly sure what to do.   I've done the following:

```
string fileToLaunch = @"Assets\SOF.xltx";
private async void LaunchFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(fileToLaunch);

        bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);

    }
```

What it gives me is a file not found error.    If I use the same command with a png file it works fine.  Any Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I open a file I've added to my Windows Store App project programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857144/how-can-i-open-a-file-ive-added-to-my-windows-store-app-project-programatically)

Comment: It could also be that you have the extension on the file wrong. Normally Excel files end in ".xlsx"

Comment: It's an excel template file