# OpenStreamForReadAsync fails with "The Parameter is Incorrect" from root

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to load resources that I have included in my package.  There are a few other questions similar to this (e.g. [Unable to access Asset files in Metro app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910627/unable-to-access-asset-files-in-metro-app)), but I'd like to avoid having to manually construct arbitrary `ms-appx:\\\` paths if possible.

```
// The location of everything in my package.
StorageFolder packageLocation = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
// The folder I want to load a file from
StorageFolder resources = await packageLocation.GetFolderAsync("Resources");

// I can successfully find the file, and then open a stream.
StorageFile file = await resources.GetFileAsync("Default.xml");
Stream streamFromFile = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

// Also, I can just directly open a stream for the file from the folder.
Stream streamFromFolder = await resources.OpenStreamForReadAsync("Default.xml");

// Error: The parameter is incorrect
Stream streamFromRoot = await packageLocation.OpenStreamForReadAsync("Resources/Default.xml")
```

I've tried many combinations including `./Resources/...`, `/Resources/...`, `ms-appx:///Resources/...`.  Why doesn't it work from the root folder?

**Note:** I haven't verified it yet, but I feel like I have the same issue with other 'root' folders such as `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test with the following syntax.

```
var file = await packageLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Resources\Default.xml");
```

or using stream

```
var stream = await packageLocation.OpenStreamForReadAsync(@"Resources\Default.xml");
```

Comment: The complete and utter rage that I feel at this moment in time knows no bounds.  Thank you, and chalk one up for HORRIBLE errors from UWP APIs.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to the answer provided by Jean-Sebastien I wanted to point out a few other scenarios where slashes matter.

If you use the `StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` API, this accepts a URI parameter which can be prefixed with `ms-appx:///`.

```
var uri = new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Resources\DefaultPickerView.xml");
var file1 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
```

Note that when you create the URI the back slashes are all converted into forward slashes.

On the other hand, I was unable to get `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync` to work at all, regardless of what combination of prefixes and slashes I used.  The [GetFileFromPathAsync MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync.aspx) however, does indicate that you can't use forward slashes in your path.